# Adding scope to ActiveRecord causes hierarchy error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I've just converted all of my Rails models to use `uuid` as a primary key replacement, but this breaks the `#first` and `#last` methods so I'm trying to add a default scope that sorts by `created_at` instead of `id`.

My concern looks like this:

```
# config/initializers/uuid_support.rb
module 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope -> { order 'created_at ASC' }
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, UuidSupport
```

Once this has been added, the following error gets thrown when performing a fetch on any model: `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're trying to create a concern and have your models include it. For that, I recommend a different approach and not do it through an initializer, but rather as an actual concern, the way Rails intended it.

Get rid of your initializer, and put the following code in `app/models/concerns/module_name.rb`:

```
module ModuleName # replace with desired name
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    default_scope -> { order 'created_at ASC' }
  end
end
```

If <= Rails 3, add this to `application.rb` to load the concerns:

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(
  #{config.root}/app/models/concerns
)
```

Include your concern in your models by doing

```
include ModuleName
```

at the beginning of your models.

If the reason you did this with an initializer is because you want every model to include this behavior, *now* is the time to write an initializer.

Either as monkey patch:

```
# config/initializers/name.rb
class ActiveRecord::Base
  include ModuleName
end
```

or like you did:

```
# config/initializers/name.rb
ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ModuleName
```

Comment: Unfortunately I still get an error when using an initializer (with any of the methods). `ActiveRecord::ActiveRecordError: ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord`. The source that is throwing the error is here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb/

Comment: Also, including the concern directly into any specific model, `include UuidSupport`, works fine.