# ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm trying to create a Rails plugin. For the most part, what I've written works. However, there's a problem with associations. When I try to call an association, I get this error:

```
ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord
```

At the moment, the plugin looks like this:

```
module ControlledVersioning
  module ActsAsVersionable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      has_many :versions, as: :versionable

      after_create :create_initial_version
    end

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_versionable(options = {})

        cattr_accessor :versionable_attributes
        self.versionable_attributes = options[:versionable_attributes]
      end
    end

    private
    def create_initial_version
      version = versions.create
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ControlledVersioning::ActsAsVersionable
```

Again, the error message is triggered whenever I try to call the association. I used debugger in the `after_create` callback and tried running:

```
> versions.create
*** ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord

> versions
*** ActiveRecord::Base doesn't belong in a hierarchy descending from ActiveRecord

> Version.new
#<Version id: nil, versionable_id: nil, versionable_type: nil>
```

Comment: You might find this answer usefull, also read the comments on the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824470/adding-scope-to-activerecord-causes-hierarchy-error

Comment: Not sure that applies in this case. As this is a plugin, I can't include the concerns directly in the models. I'm using the same format that's recommended by the Rails Guides, as you can see [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/plugins.html#add-an-instance-method). They're using concerns inside a plugin and it seems to work fine in their case.

Comment: Decided to look at how [paperclip](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/lib/paper_trail/has_paper_trail.rb) handled things. Rather than using a concern, they include all the associations and callbacks within `has_paper_trail` function. Followed suit with my plugin and everything worked fine.

Comment: After running into this with a `scope` call, I just made a custom method. For scopes, it's [just about equivalent](http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/) since Rails 3. Same logic might apply to associations.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need to change in your code in order for it to work.

First, `versions` is a reserved keyboard from rails -- you can't have a relationship with that name - (I used the name `versionings` in order to make it work)

Also, you want to make sure to just add `has_many` versionings for the models that want to `acts_as_versionable` - meaning, move `has_many :versionings, as: :versionable, class_name: 'Version'` and `after_create :create_initial_version` calls to inside the `acts_as_versionable` method.

Here's how all together will look like:

```
module ControlledVersioning
  module ActsAsVersionable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    module ClassMethods
      def acts_as_versionable(options = {})
        has_many :versionings, as: :versionable, class_name: 'Version'
        after_create :create_initial_version

        cattr_accessor :versionable_attributes
        self.versionable_attributes = options[:versionable_attributes]
      end
    end

    private

    def create_initial_version
      version = versionings.create
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.send :include, ControlledVersioning::ActsAsVersionable
```

Doing those changes made the plugin work for me:

```
irb(main):003:0> Post.create!
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Post Create (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "posts" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2019-07-16 08:55:13.768196"], ["updated_at", "2019-07-16 08:55:13.768196"]]
  Version Create (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "versions" ("versionable_type", "versionable_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["versionable_type", "Post"], ["versionable_id", 3], ["created_at", "2019-07-16 08:55:13.772246"], ["updated_at", "2019-07-16 08:55:13.772246"]]
   (2.0ms)  commit transaction
=> #<Post id: 3, created_at: "2019-07-16 08:55:13", updated_at: "2019-07-16 08:55:13", name: nil>
irb(main):004:0> Post.last.versionings
  Post Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY "posts"."id" DESC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Version Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "versions".* FROM "versions" WHERE "versions"."versionable_id" = ? AND "versions"."versionable_type" = ? LIMIT ?  [["versionable_id", 3], ["versionable_type", "Post"], ["LIMIT", 11]]
=> #<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<Version id: 2, versionable_type: "Post", versionable_id: 3, created_at: "2019-07-16 08:55:13", updated_at: "2019-07-16 08:55:13">]>
irb(main):005:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try extending active record in an initializer instead of including it.

**initializers/acts_as_versionable.rb**

`ActiveRecord::Base.extend(ControlledVersioning::ActsAsVersionable)`

Also in development; or any environment that reloads the files you'll likely see an error like `has been removed from the module tree but is still active`.  Make sure you're plugin file is in config.eager_load_paths and not actually in a concern path.