# How to add the `audited` method calls to all ActiveRecord models in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, acts-as-audited

I am adding the Audited-ActiveRecord gem to my Rails 4 application.
In order to implement the gem I need to add an `audited` method call to each model.

Is it possible to include this method in a single location instead of having to add it to each of my ActiveRecord models?

https://rubygems.org/gems/audited-activerecord

The audited gem allows me to do paste `audited` into each model however as I'm trying to add auditing without having to paste `audited` into 50+ existing models as well as future models.

For example:

```
class ModelOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  ...
end

class ModelTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  ...
end

class ModelN < ActiveRecord::Base
  audited
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help.I ended up just adding the `audited` method manually to each ActiveRecord model as shown in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `audited` on ActiveRecord::Base using an initializer. This will include it into all your ActiveRecord models.

```
# config/initializers/audited.rb
module Audited
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    audited
  end
end

ActiveRecord::Base.include Audited
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concerns` to do that, however you must include this module from `concerns` in each model files. For example:

```
class SomethingModel
  include Auditable
  #...
end

class OtherModel
  include Auditable
  #...
end


# app/models/concerns/auditable.rb
module Auditable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  #Your methods from Audited-Active-Record
end
```

Comment: I tried this method a few different ways however the result throws an exception. This answer did help me find a different answer that lead me to my final approach. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20824470/adding-scope-to-activerecord-causes-hierarchy-error Thanks again.